# Initialize value in UnsafeMutableRawPointer in swift using calloc function

Tags: c, swift

I am new in swift so if this question look improper to you please ignore. I simply want to do this in swift 3.0

```
int main()
{
    int i, n;
    int *a;

    printf("Number of elements to be entered:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    a = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter %d numbers:\n",n);
    for( i=0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    printf("The numbers entered are: ");
    for( i=0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
    {
       printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    free( a );

    return(0);
}
```

I've tried this but have no luck it says can't assign value of 'CChar' to 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer'. Can anyone help me? Ignore the printf.

```
typealias set = (CChar, CChar, CChar, CChar, CChar)
let str = "Hello"
var cs = str.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
var stringSet = set(cs[0], cs[1], cs[2], cs[3], cs[4])
var p = calloc(5, MemoryLayout<CChar>.size)
p = &stringSet.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: Thanks! Can you solve my problem?

Comment: Not with the code formatted the way it is. There were a grand total of... 0 improvements made in that edit.

Comment: Why are you using `calloc`?

Comment: Because I want to execute stdlib C functions in Swift.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm somewhat unclear about the main goal here.  The initial question suggests it's just about writing a Swift command line utility that reads some numbers from the console.  However, subsequent comments indicate you are trying to use Swift to write to memory allocated in C.  Or is it something else?

Comment: Actually I am trying to write swift code for memory allocation and initialize a value in it using calloc.

Comment: `calloc()` does not initialize memory or values, it allocates memory.  So, are you trying to call `calloc()` from Swift and then write something to that memory using Swift?  That's doable, I just want to make sure I understand what's desired.

Comment: I want to initialize value in a pointer location using swift. You are right. `calloc()` returns an `UnsafeMutablePointer`. But I want to work with this pointer like a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example.

```
// Allocate memory for 5 32-bit signed integers in Swift using calloc():
let myPtr = calloc(5, MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)

// Tell Swift how you're going to use the memory:
if let intPtr = myPtr?.bindMemory(to: Int32.self, capacity: 5) {
    // If bindMemory() is successful, place 2 ints in the array
    intPtr[0] = 123;
    intPtr[1] = 321;

    // Give the array to a C function (why would you want to use calloc(), unless 
    // some C code was involved?)
    workWithIntPtr(intPtr)

    // The C function modified the array, see what happened:
    print("After calling C code, the 3rd element of the array is \(intPtr[2])")
}
```

The C function is here:

```
void workWithIntPtr( int32_t * p)
{
    printf("The 1st 2 elements of the array are %d\n and %d\n", p[0], p[1]);
    p[2] = 555;
}
```

Please see the relevant Swift and C documentation.  Of course, the C code needs to be exposed to Swift via a bridging header.  Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks! That actually helps. Can you please explain what is the purpose of _capacity_ in `bindMemory`. I mean, I can assign more than five values in `intPtr`. So why do you set _capacity_ to five?

Comment: This is just an example based on your question.  See Apple documentation to understand Swift standard lib API.  For this particular method, it's at https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsaferawpointer/2428875-bindmemory